# Approximation of a sum defining the expectation value for Big-O of an algorithm

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, harmonic-numbers

I am considering an algorithm for sampling from a collection without replacement. The algorithm I am considering is complex in that its runtime explodes under certain conditions. I am not concerned with the efficiency of the algorithm, but rather the maths concerned with determining big-O.

Consider a population or collection to be sampled from of size $N$ and the desired resulting sample size of $k$.

The algorithm I am considering is practically very similar to the one discussed in [this question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823689/what-is-the-big-o-of-code-that-uses-random-number-generators#39824568). The difference being that, where they consider a specific case of $k=N$, I am considering a more general case where $k\leq{N}$.

I have calculated that the expectation value for the number of iterations is:
$\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{N}{N+1-i}.$

This can be rewritten to: $N\sum_{i=N+1-k}^{N}\frac{1}{i}.$

Is there a good approximation of this function?

I know that if the rewritten sum runs from $i=1$ to $N$, then a good approximation would be $N\ln{N}$. This is from [the aforementioned question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823689/what-is-the-big-o-of-code-that-uses-random-number-generators#39824568). This described big-O for the specific case where $k=N$.

Comment: Hi - welcome to MSE. Since you know $\sum_{i = 1}^N \tfrac 1i$ can be approximated by $\ln N$, you can write $\sum_{i = N + 1 - k}^N \tfrac 1i = \sum_{i = 1}^N \tfrac 1i - \sum_{i = 1}^{N - k} \tfrac 1i$...

Comment: Thank you. So can we say that $\sum_{i=N++1-k}^{N}\frac{1}{i} = \ln{N} - \ln{(N-k)}$. Which can be rewritten as $\ln{\frac{N}{N-k}}$?

Comment: From modelling this, it seems to be a decent approximation where $k<<N$. The approximation starts to deviate as $k$ gets closer to $N$

Comment: Hi Nick. How familiar are you with [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) of big-O classes? If you're concerned about the bound not working when $k=N$, you can instead take $\ln(N+1)-\ln(N+1-k)$. This is actually better than a big-O bound, it's a $\Theta$-bound which is valid for all $N$ and $k$, which is to say the error *ratio* is bounded above and below for all $N$ and $k$. (I believe it's between $1$ and $1.5$). Big-O analysis generally has little to do with the absolute error - EG merge sort doesn't take anywhere near $n\log n$ actual steps.

Comment: Thanks Izaak. I will have to think on this and study big-O classes. For now, my current understanding of the problem is sufficient to move towards a practical solution I think. :)